# Is there any way to open a popup outside the dimensions of the Application in Flex 3

Tags: flex3, popup

I am creating a flex application with application height 50 . I want a pop up to be displayed outside the main application in the browser. Is it possible?? Plz reply

Answer (score 0):

AS3 generally uses navigateToURL to make the browser jump to a new page - for instance:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://stackoverflow.com/'), '_blank');
```

Comment: @matt_lohkamp I dont want to open a new url in another window but i want to open a Titlewindow outside the Application bounds in Flex 3